# conversion fftw_complex to std::complex

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, fftw

I used FFTW to calculate FFT of a complex vector .
the `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` successfully converted to `fftw_complex` array , but now i need to convert the output aray (which is an array with variables of fftw-complex type ) again to `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` and can not do this .
how may i do this conversion ?

the vector has converted to fftw_complex array in this way :

```
for (int i = 0 ;  i< fftrate ; i++){
       memcpy( &fftwarray[i], &inputvector[i]sizeof(fftw_complex ) );
            }
```

but i get segmentation fault err when i wanna convert back output with :

```
for (int j = 0 ;  j< fftrate ; j++){
 memcpy( &outputvector[j], &fftwarray[j],sizeof(fftw_complex ) );

           }
```

also i have tried reinterpret casting and it did not work .

EDIT :  example of program :

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>>input,output ;
std::vector<std::complex<double>> fft (void) {
   fftw_complex in[fftrate], out[fftrate];
   for (int i = 0 ;  i< fftrate ; i++){
       memcpy( &in[i], &input[i], sizeof( fftw_complex ) );
   }
   fftw_plan p=fftw_create_plan(fftrate, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
   fftw_one(p, in, out);
   for (int j = 0 ;  j< fftrate ; j++){
       memcpy( &output[j], &out[j], sizeof( fftw_complex ) );
   }


   return output;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mre] so that we see how all the variables are declared.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo thanks for your comment . i will edit the question .

Comment: What is `din` that you have in the added code.

Comment: A side note: VLAs like: `fftw_complex in[fftrate], out[fftrate];` are not a part of C++ standard.

Comment: In the code shown `output` is an empty `vector` so `output[j]` is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Another issue: I don't see where `output` is allocated with the proper size (`fftrate`).

Comment: Also: `output` is declared as `std::vector<std::complex<double>>`, but the function is declared to return `std::vector<std::complex<float>>`....?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo it was a fault , i edited the name . and function output .

Comment: @G.m. yes i think its the answer . thanks <3

Comment: It's still not a [mre], but why are you involving `std::complex<double>` instead of using `fftw_complex` everywhere?

Comment: Your `memcpy`s are probably UB. It's mostly the same as: `fftw_one(p, reinterpret_cast<double*>(input.data()), reinterpret_cast<double*>(output.data()));` (without the unnecessary arrays).

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo because I want to bind code to python and fftw_complex is not a bindable data type .

Comment: @MohammadHassanRezaei Ok, then do it the opposite way around and only use `std::vector<std::complex<double>>`. I added an answer for that.

Comment: Can u use a debugger? If yes, check the value of `j` when segfault is raised. Is the `output` vector properly resized to `fftrate` value? I bet the problem is there, because otherwise the code provided is fine. Although `fft` should accept `input` vector as a parameter, and `output` vector should be declared as a local variable. If you wish to save on allocations, function `fft` should accept `output` as output parameter (by mutable reference). This is because global (or even just shared) variables are the root of evil, which is demonstrated by this example (though I just guess here).

Answer (score 2):

From [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex):

> For any pointer to an element of an array of `complex<T>` named `p` and any valid array index `i`, `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i]` is the real part of the complex number `p[i]`, and `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1]` is the imaginary part of the complex number `p[i]`.

Since those are guaranteed, just skip the `fftw_complex` arrays completely:

```cpp
std::vector<std::complex<double>> fft() {
    output.resize(input.size());
    
    fftw_plan p = fftw_create_plan(fftrate, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    fftw_one(p, reinterpret_cast<double*>(input.data()),
                reinterpret_cast<double*>(output.data()));

   return output;
}
```

Comment: Hello. thank you for your answer . I got your idea . and i solved the problem with resizing my output vector . but unfortunately reinterpret casting does not work in this case .

Comment: @MohammadHassanRezaei In what way doesn't it work? Are you sure `input.size() == output.size() == fftrate` ?